Could anyone help me figure out where the flow of my MIPS program is going wrong?
I'm writing a MIPS program (simulated on qtSpim) for a class that's supposed to do the following: read two integers from user input, determine whether each one is even or odd, compare them, and then perform a user-determined operation on them. All of that seems to work perfectly except for the comparison portion-- the program just skips it. It doesn't break, it doesn't behave oddly otherwise, it just doesn't do any comparing. It's entirely possible I'm missing something obvious, but I just don't see it! Could someone better at assembly than me help me figure out where I'm going wrong?
.text
Main:
# Initialize registers
li $s5, 0
li $s6, 2

Int1:
# Prompt for the integer to enter
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt1
syscall

# Read the integer and save it in $s0
li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s0, $v0
addi $s3, $s0, 0
jal CheckEven

Int2:
# Prompt for another integer to enter
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt2
syscall

# Read the second integer and save it in $s1
li $v0, 5
syscall
move $s1, $v0
addi $s3, $s1, 0
jal CheckEven
nop

# Comparison logic
Compare:
#print first integer
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s0
syscall

beq $s0, $s1, Equal
slt $s3, $s0, $s1
bne $s3, $zero, Less

Greater:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, gt
syscall
j FinishCompare

Less:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, lt
syscall
j FinishCompare

Equal:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, et
syscall

FinishCompare:
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s1
syscall

# Prompt for operator
Operator:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt3
syscall

# Read the operator and save it in $s2
li $v0, 12
syscall
addi $s2, $zero, 0
move $s2, $v0

# Branch to addition
li $t0, '+'
beq $s2, $t0, Add

# Branch to subtraction
li $t0, '-'
beq $s2, $t0, Subtract

# Branch to multiplication
li $t0, '*'
beq $s2, $t0, Multiply

# Branch to division
li $t0, '/'
beq $s2, $t0, Divide

# Handle unexpected character
li $v0, 4
la $a0, error
syscall
j Operator

Add:
add $s4, $s0, $s1
j Print
nop

Subtract:
sub $s4, $s0, $s1
j Print
nop

Multiply:
mul $s4, $s0, $s1
j Print
nop

Divide:
div $s4, $s0, $s1
mflo $s4
mfhi $s5
j Print
nop

Print:

# Line break
li $v0, 4
la $a0, br
syscall

# Print 1st value
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s0
syscall

# Print operator
li $v0, 11
move $a0, $s2
syscall

# Print 2nd value
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s1
syscall

# Print equals sign
li $v0, 4
la $a0, e
syscall

# Print result
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s4
syscall

#branch for division
beq $s5, $zero, Exit
li $v0, 4
la $a0, remainder
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s5
syscall

#Check whether user-supplied integers are even
CheckEven:
div $s3, $s3, $s6
mfhi $s3
beq $s3, 0, PrintEven
li $v0, 4
la $a0, odd
syscall
addi $s3, $zero, 0
jr $ra

#Branch to print if even
PrintEven:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, even
syscall
jr $ra

# Exit the program
Exit:
li $v0, 10
syscall

.data
prompt1: .asciiz "\nPlease enter an integer: "
prompt2: .asciiz "\nPlease enter another integer: "
prompt3: .asciiz "\nPlease choose a math operation (+, -, *, or /): "
error: .asciiz "\nNot gonna work!"
remainder: .asciiz " with remainder "

br: .asciiz "\n"
e: .asciiz " = "
gt: .asciiz " is greater than "
lt: .asciiz " is less than than "
et: .asciiz " is equal to "

even: .asciiz "(even)"
odd: .asciiz "(odd)"

I've tried moving sections around, I've tried explicitly telling the program to jump to the comparison logic after reading the second integer, but nothing seems to work. The program continues to run smoothly, minus the comparison portion.

Use your simulator to single step the program and see how it skips the part. PS: it works here.

@Jester Tried that and realized I was just loading the wrong file. It works after all and I'm an idiot. Thank you!
